# Explain the usage of procs in an rspec context

Tags: ruby, rspec, proc

Here is an expectation that utilizes a custom RSpec matcher, yield_variables:

```
specify { expect{ |p| [3,4,5].my_each(&p) }.to yield_variables [3,4,5] }
```

my yield_variables matcher's matches? method utilizes a custom class called Probe (Probe is a stripped down version of RSpec's [yield probe](http://rspec.info/documentation/2.99/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers/BuiltIn/YieldProbe.html)):

```
...
    def matches? block
        ap Probe.probe block
        # note i am inspecting what is returned by Probe.probe with ap
    end
...


# Probe class is what all my questions are about!
class Probe
    attr_accessor :yielded_args
    def initialize
        self.yielded_args = []
    end

    def self.probe(block)
        probe = new
        block.call(probe)
        probe.yielded_args
    end

    def to_proc
        Proc.new { |*args| yielded_args << args }
    end
end
```

Now my ap inside `matches?` reports this: `[3,4,5]` That is what I expect. However, I have no idea how the Probe class works!!

**Problem 1)** the matches? block

Normally, the argument we pass to matches? is what we expect the subject to return. i.e, I expect `[3,4,5]` to be passed into block.
Instead, `|p| [3,4,5].my_each(&p)` is passed into block, as a proc. Why is this?

**Problem 2)** block.call(probe)

I'm a bit shakey on procs so please explain slowly. But basically, here we take a new instance of my Probe class and 'send' the block to it, as an argument. That's how I'd explain it to the best of my abilities, but I might have it totally wrong so please explain slowly.

**Problem 3)** How is to_proc called?

How on earth is .to_proc called automatically? I believe it's called automatically by block.call(probe). Is to_proc an automatically called method like initialize? Is it automatically called whenever the class is sent to a proc? (Btw, the phrase the class is sent to a proc doesn't even make 100% sense to me - please explain. The block isn't passed into the class as an argument anymore. Or if the block is passed as an argument the block.call syntax feels really weird and backwards)

**Problem 4)** to_proc

How does to_proc have access to the expectation's subject i.e. `|p| [3,4,5].my_each(&p)` ? How is Proc.new 's *args automatically populated with every single possible yield argument, even though I've only passed in |p| ? How does **Proc.new loop along with my my_each, incrementally placing all my args in an array?** How does Proc.new have any knowledge of the subject `|p| [3,4,5].my_each(&p)`? How?? Explain please, and thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block based marchers work a little differently to other matchers. Typically you want to do something that would not be possible if the expression you were interested in was evaluated and the result passed to you.

For example the `raises_error` matcher wants to execute the block itself to see that the correct exception is raised and the `change` matcher wants to evaluate some other expression before and after to see if it changes in the specified way. This is why you are passed a block rather than the value.

The block you are passing to `expect` takes 1 argument and uses this as the block in the call to `my_each`, so when your Probe.probe method calls the block it has to pass something as the value. You've phrased as "sending the block to the probe instance" but it is the other way around: the block is called using probe as its argument.

The block executes and calls `my_each`. Inside here `p` is the instance of `Probe`. Prefixing an argument with a & tells ruby that this argument should be used as the method's block (the method being my_each). If the argument is not already a proc ruby calls `to_proc` on it. This is how Probe#to_proc is called

Assuming that `my_each` behaves in a similar way to normal `each` it will call its block (ie the return value of `to_proc`) once for each of the values in the array.

Normally your matcher would then compare the return value from `Probe.probe` to the actual value.

Comment: Thanks, cleared up a lot of things, but how is *args populated by all of `my_each`' possible piped arguments? How does *args automatically balloon up and pass my_each `|v, count, somethingelse, ect|` ?

Comment: Well in your case it's only being passed one value at a time and it's not being passed my_each's arguments but the values my_each yields

Comment: But if use each_with_index I get back an array countaining each elements index and value. Even though I haven't written `|v,i|` anywhere... *args is magically set to `[0,'the first value'] [1,'the second value'] [2,'the third value']` each time. How is args creating these arrays. As I say, I haven't specified `|v,i|` anywhere...

Comment: The proc returned by Probe#to_proc uses *args to get all the arguments passed to it, no matter how many there are

Comment: How does it even know to put the key value pairs in an array? If I did `map |v, i|` `v` and `i` would be available, so how is `yielded_args << args` putting them in a nice array? :P

Comment: That's what the splat  ( * ) does

Comment: Mate. I got it. Thanks so much. to_proc returns out new proc and so the spec sort of looks like this:

`my_each( *WHAT IS RETURNED BY TO_PROC* )` thankyou

Comment: is it possible to send an argument to `to_proc` via `.probe?`

Comment: to_proc cannot take any arguments.